# Make Text widget overflow when parent widget cannot contain the text in it

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I have a `Text` widget in a Row like this in my code. I added `Expanded`, `overflow` and `maxLines` so that the text could be repond well to the changes to the device width, but couldn't get the text from actually over-flowing.

```
Row(
  children: [
    const SizedBox(width: 10),
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        widget.text ?? '',
        maxLines: widget.maxLines,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: AppStyle.title,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Can you include an image of your desire output and point out what exactly went wrong ?